# is a CORS request with preflight time consuming?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, cors, preflight

I use an AJAX request to send data through POST to another domain.
As my content-type is not standard (it's JSON format), a preflight request is needed. ( with request Method: OPTIONS)

As described in this [cross domain XHR call chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flowchart_showing_Simple_and_Preflight_XHR.svg) from wikipedia

I am wondering if this is time consuming as the browser will have to reach the server twice or not ? Maybe it depends on each browser behavior ?

Do I gain some time by using content-type "plain-text" to avoid the preflight request instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a request. It takes time. It shouldn't take a *significant* amount of time though, so don't prematurely optimise.

Comment: That's the question, is it really a second request ?  Any reference on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is. The diagram you linked to says it is. You could also look at the CORS spec, the MDN CORS guide or just check the Network tab in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: Oh you're right, I've should have seen that: in the Network tab, if the request succeed we can see one call with Method "OPTION" and one other with method POST.  thanks.